# Using the results from NDSolve in another equation

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions

I want to use the results `sol` returned from `NDSolve` (values of `f` at different `z`) in `acc` and also `f[z]` appears in my `Gam` variable. How can I get these values?

```
sol = NDSolve[
    {Dt[f[z], {z, 2}] == YY, f[0] == 1, f'[0] == 0}, 
    f[z], {z, 0, 6*10^(-4)}]

Plot[Evaluate[f[z] /. sol], {z, 0, 6*10^(-4)}, PlotRange -> All]

A1 = Exp[(-3/2)*t]* t^((3*n - 1)/2)* (LaguerreL[m, n, t]^2)

A2 = 1.0 - ((1/Gam)*(Wpo / Wo)^2) - (ko*vth/Wo)^2

A3 = 
  (n + 2*m)*LaguerreL[m, n, t] - t*LaguerreL[m, n, t] - 
  2*(m + n)*LaguerreL[m - 1, n, t]

G1 = A1*A3/A2

G = Integrate[G1, {t, 0, Infinity}]

acc = (Factorial[m]/Factorial[m + n])*((Wpo^2*ro)/(c*Wo))*(E1^(1/2))/f[z]^2)*G

---

    m = 2

    n = 1

    E1 = 1.5
    (*intensity=E1=b E1^2*)

    Wpo = 1.7683*10^(15)

    Wo = 1.7773*10^(15)

    ro = 15.0*10^(-6)

    c = 3.0*10^8

    ko = 1.38* 10^(-23)

    to = 10^7

    me = 9.1*10^(-31)

    vth = 2*ko*to/(3*me*(c^2))

    Gam = (1 + (E1/((f[z])^2)) t^n Exp[-t] (LaguerreL[m, n, t])^2)^(-1/2)

    s1 = Exp[-t] t^(n - 1) LaguerreL[m, n, t]^2

    s2 = Exp[-t] t^(n - 1) (LaguerreL[m - 1, n, t])^2

    s3 = Exp[-t] t^(n - 1) (LaguerreL[m, n, t]*LaguerreL[m - 1, n, t])

    s4 = t^(2*n + 1) Exp[-t] (LaguerreL[m, n, t])^2

    s5 = (2*n + 4*m)*(LaguerreL[m, n, t])^2/t - 
      2*(LaguerreL[m, n, t])^2 - 
      4*(m + n)*LaguerreL[m, n, t]*LaguerreL[m - 1, n, t]/t

    Y1 = ((n + 2*m)^2 Integrate[s1, {t, 0, Infinity}] + 
       Factorial[m + n]*(2*m + n + 1)/Factorial[m] + 
       4*(m + n)^2 Integrate[s2, {t, 0, Infinity}] - 
       2*(n + 2*m)*Factorial[m + n]/Factorial[m] - 
       4*(m + n)*(n + 2*m)*Integrate[s3, {t, 0, Infinity}])

    Y = (1 - (3/2)*(E1/((f[z])^2)*
           t^n Exp[-t] (LaguerreL[m, n, t])^2)) (t^(2*n + 
           1) Exp[-t] (LaguerreL[m, n, t])^2) ((2*n + 
           4*m)*(LaguerreL[m, n, t])^2/t - 2*(LaguerreL[m, n, t])^2 - 
        4*(m + n)*LaguerreL[m, n, t]*LaguerreL[m - 1, n, t]/t)

    Y3 = Integrate[Y, {t, 0, Infinity}]

    Y4 = Factorial[
        m]/(Factorial[
          m + n]*(2*m + n + 1)*(f[z])^3)*(Y1 + (E1*Wpo^2*ro^2/(c^2)) Y3)

    Y5 = (1/f[z])*(D[f[z], z])^2

    YY = Y4 - Y5

    sol = NDSolve[{Dt[f[z], {z, 2}] == YY, f[0] == 1, f'[0] == 0}, 
      f[z], {z, 0, 6*10^(-4)}]

    Plot[Evaluate[f[z] /. sol], {z, 0, 6*10^(-4)}, PlotRange -> All]

    A1 = Exp[(-3/2)*t]* t^((3*n - 1)/2)* (LaguerreL[m, n, t]^2)

    A2 = 1.0 - ((1/Gam)*(Wpo / Wo)^2) - (ko*vth/Wo)^2

    A3 = (n + 2*m)* LaguerreL[m, n, t] - t* LaguerreL[m, n, t] - 
      2*(m + n)* LaguerreL[m - 1, n, t]

    G1 = A1*A3/A2

    G = Integrate[G1, {t, 0, Infinity}]

    acc = (Factorial[m]/ Factorial[m + n])* ((Wpo^2 *ro)/(c * Wo))*((E1^(1/2))/f[z]^2) * G


I want to plot acc by using the value of F[z] in the integration of G
```

Comment: Before you can use `NDSolve` your ode must be properly defined: `YY ` isn't defined, use  `D[f[z], {z, 2}]`(not `Dt`).

Comment: I had defined it but not shown here. The result till plot equation is achieved, but I want to use the solution of f[z] from the first equation sol in my last equation.

Comment: Please check the document of `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) carefully, you cannot live without this function when using _Mathematica_.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your ode is well defined(`YY` still  isn't defined ) you can use   `NDSolveValue`(I changed`Dt`to `D` in your original ode and`YY=1`) :

```
F = NDSolveValue[{D[f[z], {z, 2}] == 1, f[0] == 1, f'[0] == 0}, f , {z, 0, 6*10^(-4)}]
```

Now you can use `F[z]` in your calculations!

```
F[.0002] (*1.*)
Plot[ F[z] , {z, 0, 6*10^(-4)}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Actually, I want to ask whether I can use this F[z] at some other place, where a new equation is a function of F[z]?  Can I have a plot between the new-made function and z?

Comment: You can use `F[z]` like  other built in functions.

Comment: but it is pasting the same function as it is. I mean interpolated function graph as it is

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what you really want to do with `F[z]`

Comment: No problem. My issue is solved now. Thanks for your help.